# Как запустить один метод(задачу) за другим, но в одном потоке?

Tags: android

Как запустить один метод(задачу) за другим, но в одном потоке?

Comment: так и хочется ответить разделив их ";" Но все же вам придется раскрыть чуть побольше, что вы имеете в виду :)

Comment: Быстро-решительно!

Comment: А что у вас вызвало трудности? Покажите код.

Comment: <названиеВашегоПервогоМетода>();    
<названиеВашегоВторогоМетода>();

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends ListFragmentStackActivity {
    method1();
}

public void method1() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Я метод 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    method2();
}

public void method2() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Я метод 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    method1();
}
```